Mocking method that returns IAsyncEnumerable throws null reference exception
I'm using .NET 8, NSubstitute, NUnit.Framework.
I'm trying to mock a method that returns IAsyncEnumerable. When I'm trying to mock this method with other conditions, I'm getting null reference exception from NSubstitute:
var awsInterfaceMock = Substitute.For<IAWSInterface>();

var objectsList1 = new List<(List<string>, List<S3Object>)>();
objectsList1.Add((new List<string>() { "Folder_1" },
new List<S3Object>()));
awsInterfaceMock.ListObjectsAsync(Arg.Is<ListObjectsV2Request>(l => l.Prefix == null), 
Arg.Any<Amazon.RegionEndpoint>(), Arg.Any<string>())
.Returns(objectsList1.ToAsyncEnumerable());

var objectsList2 = new List<(List<string>, List<S3Object>)>();
objectsList2.Add((new List<string>(),
new List<S3Object>() {
    new S3Object() {
        BucketName = "bucket1-dev1",
        Key = "Folder_1/File_1.zip",
        Size = 100,
        Owner = new Owner()
            {
                DisplayName = "aws-fam-dev1",
                Id = "2b6d34efdee62f163c910ee856dcde18ac02ddbb679e9b1c39eea78ebb9fb1ba"
            }
        },
    new S3Object() {
        BucketName = "bucket1-dev1",
        Key = "Folder_1/File_2.zip",
        Size = 100,
        Owner = new Owner()
            {
                DisplayName = "aws-fam-dev1",
                Id = "2b6d34efdee62f163c910ee856dcde18ac02ddbb679e9b1c39eea78ebb9fb1ba"
            }
        }
    }));

awsInterfaceMock.ListObjectsAsync(Arg.Is<ListObjectsV2Request>(l => l.Prefix == "Folder_1"), 
Arg.Any<Amazon.RegionEndpoint>(), Arg.Any<string>())
.Returns(objectsList2.ToAsyncEnumerable());

The last line throws the exception.
This is the method that I try to mock:
IAsyncEnumerable<(List<string> folders, List<S3Object> files)> ListObjectsAsync(ListObjectsV2Request listObjectsV2Request, RegionEndpoint regionEndpoint, string accountArn);

If I am mocking objectsList2 only one time - everything seems to work fine
